# Sharepoint web analytics does not show any data

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, analytics, web-analytics

We installed **Sharepoint Web Analytics** some days ago (separated application pool).

Installation completed successfully.

Search works fine and returns expected results.

But reports still don't show any data :

> Data Last Updated: 03.06.2014 02:00:23 There is no data available for
>   this report. Here are some possible reasons: (1) Web Analytics has not
>   been enabled long enough to generate data; (2) There is insufficient
>   data to generate this report; (3) Data logging required for this
>   report might not be enabled; (4) Data aggregation might not be enabled
>   at the level required for this report.

What I tried :

- connect to website using different users (admin user included) and different browsers
- checked that needed services on server are started (especially analytics services)
- restart services `Web Analytics Data Processing Service` and `Web Analytics Web Service`
- checked that all services applications are started (`WSS_UsageApplication` status was `stopped` so I started it using *Sharepoint 2010 Management Shell*)
- checked service application associations (especially if `Analytics Service Application Proxy` is checked)
- manual execution of jobs (`Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job`, `Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import`, `Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing`)
- manual start of incremental crawling
- IIS restart
- virtual machine reboot
- checked scope of data logging (especially if `Enable usage data collection` and `Enable health data collection` are checked)
- checked that the .usage file are generated correctly on the disk
- checked in the Logging database (`WSS_UsageApplication`) that the `RequestUsage` view contains data collected from the .usage files
- checked that data is successfully extracted from the logging database into the staging database (`LastLoggingExtractionTime`)
- checked that data was successfully copied from the staging database to the reporting database (`LastDataCopyTime`)
- checked on the website side that `Advanced Web Analytics` feature is `Active`
- granted `ROOT\SPAppPool` full control on the `Web Analytics Service Application`
- recreate web analytics application
- cleaned sharepoint cache configuration (deleted all `.xml` files from `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\` and reinitialize `cache.ini` to `1`)
- cleaned the drive where `.usage` file are generated so the message "Drives are running out of free space.  Available drive space is less than twice the value of physical memory." does not appear anymore in ULS logs
- added `ROOT\SPAppPool` user to the `Performance Log Users` group on the local machine
- added `ROOT\SPAppPool` user to the `Farm Admin` group
- added dbowner permission for user `ROOT\SPAppPool` on `WSS_UsageApplication` and `Sharepoint_Config` databases
- install patch [2204024](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=2204024) (was already installed)
- manual execution of procedures in the staging and reporting databases (`proc_DefragmentIndices`, `proc_UpdateStatistics`, `proc_WA_CleanFloatingFeedbackData`, `proc_WA_DeleteInvalidAdjacentHierarchyData`, `proc_WA_DeleteInvalidFactData`, `proc_WA_DeleteInvalidInventoryData` in the reporting database and `proc_DefragmentIndices`, `proc_UpdateStatistics`, `proc_WA_EnsureServiceBrokerEnabled` in the staging database)
- checked that Windows service `Sharepoint 2010 Timer` is started
- checked for any message in ULS logs that could help...

All appears to work fine but I can't see any data in the reports.

Anything else I can try ?

**EDIT 14 aug 2014:**

Inventory data is collected successfully and I can see the related reports. Traffic and Search data still empty :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

last time i had a problem i wrote the following steps.
maybe they can help

1) create the web analytics service application

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266382%28v=office.14%29.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2009/11/21/step-by-step-provisioning-the-web-analytics-service-application-on-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2010-beta.aspx

2) enable "web analytics data processing service" and "web analytics web service" services on the application server
where analytics will run

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/how-does-web-analytics-works-under-sharepoint-2010

3) make sure reporting account is a member of the farm administrators group

In Central Administration, on the Home page, click Monitoring.

On Monitoring page, in the Reporting section, click Configure usage and health data collection.

On the Event Selection section, click all check boxes to select them, and then click OK.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51621/web-analytics-not-working

4) force population of results

You can run the time job manually to get the data into the analytics report straight away by going into the

***'Monitoring' section in Central Administration.***

There you will find a link under the 'Timer Jobs' heading called 'Review job definitions'.

In there will be a whole load of job definitions, look for

***'Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job'***

with the correct Web Application specified (for me it was on the 2nd page).

Click the name of the job and click the 'Run Now' button.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51621/web-analytics-not-working

5) check your reports

http://you.com/_layouts/WebAnalytics/Report.aspx?t=SummaryReport&l=s

*** troubleshoot ***

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2012/03/16/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-web-analytics.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/manharsharma/archive/2012/10/13/sharepoint-2010-web-analytics-troubleshooting-reporting-db.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I already have performed all these steps. Data is successfully moved from staging database to reporting database, it means all previous steps succeeded. However reports still don't show anything. I think we will go with another tool...

Comment: Finally we got help from an external service provider. So the problem has been solved by a [very expensive] Sharepoint consultant ;) If I remember well our test environment was pretty poor so we did a new one from production (actually a lab), then he did a cleaning in the Alternate Access Mapping configuration (some entries were not necessary), and finally it worked...